# Logitech Unifying Receiver not recognized through Belkin KVM switch, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: logitech-unifying

In Ubuntu 16.04 my wireless keyboard and mouse works when the unfying receiver is plugged directly into computer USB port, however, when same receiver is plugged into universal USB port on KVM console, it is not recognized by OS. It is recognized, however, on my Windows 10 PC.
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Robb

Answer (score 0):

After about 3 hours of fiddling with the kvm switch and moving port cables, etc etc...the unifying receiver is again recognized, and all is working again.
I was just about to do a firmware upgrade on the Belkin KVM Soho switch, and it started working on another port...yeah! I did learn to install and use the Solaar utility along the way, so I picked up a little knowledge there as well.